# Is it posible to save direction in jCarousel (autoplay) plugin?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Currently in jCarousel [auto play example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) , when you click the next or previous button it will continue to its current state, (scroll from right to left). what i want is, is it possible when you click next it will save its direction (scrolling from left to right).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the jCarousel plugin doesn't support this. So there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this, without rewriting the plugin

I tried a quick hack without rewriting (external timer, manually calling `carousel.prev()` and similar ideas) but the internals of the plugin keept getting in the way.